# Optim function returning wrong solution

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to get a function minimum with optim in R, the problem is that the par solution returned by the method is not correct and change if i introduce a different initial point. I will show you some code and the output in getting.
What am I missing?

```
> funx = function(vx) (vx[1] -2)^4 + (vx[1]-2*vx[2])^2 + -10/(vx[1]^2-vx[2])
> optim(c(0,1), funx)
$par
[1] 0.7080021 1.5315815

$value
[1] 18.03898

$counts
function gradient 
      61       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL

> optim(c(0,3), funx)
$par
[1] 1.271924 1.617791

$value
[1] -4.5036e+16

$counts
function gradient 
     237       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL

> funx(c(1.271924, 1.617791))
[1] 29566209
```

Comment: Seems to be some sort of rounding error? The function is extremely volatile near the points `1.271924, 1.617791`. Adjust them up or down just `0.000001`. I assume optim is rounding somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, this is a rounding problem.  If you feed the *exact* values back to `funx()` you get a small (i.e. very negative) value: if you round to six digits you get a large value.

```
oo <-optim(c(0,3), funx)
funx(oo$par)
## [1] -4.5036e+16
 funx(round(oo$par,6))
## [1] 29566209
```

This is indeed an ill-behaved function, you might need to take this into account when working with it.  (I'd also strongly suggest using derivative-based optimization, either calculating the derivatives yourself or using `deriv()`.)

Answer (score 0):

You may add, for instance, method = "L-BFGS-B" in your optim and define the upper and lower limits of your parameters depending on your definition of the function. It may produce values out of their original intervals.